# "Emergency Mode" on installing NFS

Tags: nfs

I installed NFS in 15.04 with the packages `rpcbind` and `nfs-common`, and when I had added my server to `/etc/fstab` and rebooted I got greeted with a nice emergency mode. Thats odd I thought, is it because of the update on the kernel I did before I rebooted? I uninstalled the NFS packages and it booted fine again. Anyone got a solution? Oh, I also tried doing `systemctl enable rpcbind` but that didn't help.

**EDIT:** I installed the packages with `apt install nfs-common rpcbind` and my fstab entry looked like `192.168.10.74:/ /mnt/nfs` but it shouldn't matter as I tried without having an fstab entry and it still gave me emergency mode.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include i) the exact commands you used to install the packages; ii) the exact error message you received; iii) the contents of your `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: There you are :)

Comment: Thanks, the fact that it occurs without the fstab entry is particularly important. What is "emergency mode"? I assume you mean that you booted to a tty? What was the exact error message and when did this "emergency mode" appear? Have you checked the files in `/var/log`?

Comment: Emergency mode is when systemd decides that "f*ck it, fix this on your own" while booting. It simply gives you a terminal as the root user.

Comment: Yes, but when does this happen? What was the last message printed to your screen? I guess you are referring to booting to init 1 and seeing the "Enter root password or hit Ctrl+D to continue" message. Is that right?

Comment: No, terdon.  This is version 15 and the questioner is describing a well-known systemd mechanism by its conventional name.  There are no runlevels, only targets.  The question is talking about _rescue mode_, isolating `rescue.target`.  (Confusingly, the target itself prints out a message reading "emergency mode", but that's actually a different `emergency.target`.  The systemd bootstrap debugging doco also calls this "emergency mode".)  `rescue.service` is running, as is everything started by `sysinit.target`, including everything brought in by `local-fs.target`.